# How to pass playbook tags to ansible-container?

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-container

I created playbooks with tags.
I want to use ansible-container to test my playbooks.
According to the Ansible documentation on [`ansible-container build`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/reference/build.html), 
it is possible to add playbook parameters, but it doesn't work.

```
ansible-container build --  --tags "pre-install, install"
```

I get the following error:

> ansible-container_1     | ERROR! the playbook: [--tags, could not be found
>   ansible_ansible-container_1 exited with code 1

Comment: Why is `docker` a tag of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between tags:

`--tags 'pre-install,install'` instead of `--tags 'pre-install, install'`